# With a simple String In Date

Tags: php, regex, datetime

Myself I have such a string

```
citation
2d6h8y4m
d - days
min - min
h - h
y - years
m - months
s - seconds
```

I would like to add today's date as saved time , ie

```
2 days , 6 hours, 8 years and 4 months
```

I know how to do it in a simple way - the loop on all the text and read in sequence numbers, but my guess is that it can be done more simply - a regex . Sorry sag on this if someone gave me such a function or somehow me clues (eg . Given pattern on one character) enough , I can Narratives

@INFO

Not understood still to drive not want to do today's date to add eg 2 days , 4 months , etc.

Ie today is 2014-11-22 5:43:45 p.m.
After the addition of I 2 days 6 hours 8 years and 4 months I have
2022-04-24 11:43:45 p.m.

Comment: Not understood still to drive not want to do today's date to add eg 2 days , 4 months , etc.

Ie today is 2014-11-22 5:43:45 p.m.
After the addition of I 2 days 6 hours 8 years and 4 months I have
2022-04-24 11:43:45 p.m.

Answer (score 0):

Separate `int` values & `char/word` by `preg_match_all()`. Create and `array()` that contains the full meaning of character (ie, h = hours). Then just `foreach()`. Example:

```
$avr = array('d'=>'days', 'min'=>'min','h'=>'hours', 'y'=>'years', 'm'=>'months', 's'=>'seconds');
$str = '2d6h8y4m';
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $int);
preg_match_all('/[a-z]+/', $str, $word);
$len = count($int[0]) - 1;
$result = '';
foreach($int[0] as $k=>$v){
    if($len == $k){
        $result .= ' and ' . $v . '  ' . $avr[$word[0][$k]];
    }else{
        $suf = ($k == 0) ? '' : ', ';
        $result .= $suf . $v . '  ' . $avr[$word[0][$k]];
    }
}
echo $result;
```

**Output:**

```
2  days, 6  hours, 8  years and 4  months
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're looking for is

```
(\d+)d(\d+)h(\d+)y(\d+)m
```

`\d` matches any digit. From this you can extract what was matched between the brackets. Here is the full code:

```
preg_match("(\d+)d(\d+)h(\d+)y(\d+)m", "2d6h8y4m", $matches);
```

Now `$matches` will be an array containing what is matched between the brackets. `$matches[0]` will be the first bracket (the day), `$matches[1]` will be the first bracket (the hour), etc.

Comment: Not understood still to drive not want to do today's date to add eg 2 days , 4 months , etc. Ie today is 2014-11-22 5:43:45 p.m. After the addition of I 2 days 6 hours 8 years and 4 months I have 2022-04-24 11:43:45 p.m

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Why don't you store intervals in [ISO-8601 duration format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), like for example: `P8Y5M2DT6H` ?

```
$date = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P8Y5M2DT6H');
$date->add($interval);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/225482)</kbd>